# python netcdf on M1

Tags: python, apple-m1, netcdf4

I am trying to install netcdf4-python on a MacOSX Monterey with M1 processor.

I installed without problems hdf5 and netcdf using brew.

However, after cloning the netcfd4 python repo at https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python, when I then try to install netcdf4-python with `python setup.py build` I get the error below. I googled a bit and it seems that the brew installation of hdf5 does not include `hdf5.pc` so I wonder if someone found a way to circumvent this problem.

I am running python 3.9.9

Thanks for your help

Marco

```
Collecting netcdf4
  Using cached netCDF4-1.5.8.tar.gz (767 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/mpagani/.pyenv/versions/3.9.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/vpmn9x657d3gzwvrx2vryvc80000gn/T/pip-install-y1xv724i/netcdf4_95eb462bb7b74fdfbac8a5de4965d36b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/j5/vpmn9x657d3gzwvrx2vryvc80000gn/T/pip-install-y1xv724i/netcdf4_95eb462bb7b74fdfbac8a5de4965d36b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/j5/vpmn9x657d3gzwvrx2vryvc80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-bbawe1ww
       cwd: /private/var/folders/j5/vpmn9x657d3gzwvrx2vryvc80000gn/T/pip-install-y1xv724i/netcdf4_95eb462bb7b74fdfbac8a5de4965d36b/
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Package hdf5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `hdf5.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'hdf5' found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/j5/vpmn9x657d3gzwvrx2vryvc80000gn/T/pip-install-y1xv724i/netcdf4_95eb462bb7b74fdfbac8a5de4965d36b/setup.py", line 409, in <module>
      _populate_hdf5_info(dirstosearch, inc_dirs, libs, lib_dirs)
    File "/private/var/folders/j5/vpmn9x657d3gzwvrx2vryvc80000gn/T/pip-install-y1xv724i/netcdf4_95eb462bb7b74fdfbac8a5de4965d36b/setup.py", line 360, in _populate_hdf5_info
      raise ValueError('did not find HDF5 headers')
  ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers
  reading from setup.cfg...
  using nc-config...
  checking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/netcdf/4.8.1/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/netcdf/4.8.1/include
  nc-config did provide path to HDF5 headers, search standard locations...
      HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
  checking /Users/mpagani/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /Users/mpagani/include
  checking /usr/local/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /usr/local/include
  checking /sw/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /sw/include
  checking /opt/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /opt/include
  checking /opt/local/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /opt/local/include
  checking /usr/include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /usr/include
  ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Any luck @marco?

Comment: @CharmingRobot After some googling, I found this: https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/562. Following the instruction provided I managed to complete the installation from sources.